# ngClass one conditional and other from variable

Tags: css, sass, ng-class

I have the following data structure:

```
  this.filters = [
  {
    key: 'filter1',
    active: true,
    class: 'filter1Class'
  },
  {
    key: 'filter2',
    active: false,
    class: 'filter2Class'
  },
  {
    key: 'filter3',
    active: true,
    class: 'filter3Class'
  }
];
```

And with this I want to create some icons in my html, every icon will have each own css class and it can be enabled or not depending on the active flag in the model.

My classes are quite simples, every `filterNClass` is just a color and the one I applied to set it enabled or nor is an opacity value:

```
.disabled {
   opacity: 0.2;
}

.filter1Class {
   color: #1993a0;
}

.filter2Class {
   color: #720053;
}

.filter3Class {
   color: #000055;
}
```

this is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
  <mat-icon [ngClass]="filter.class"
            [ngClass]="{disabled: !filter.active}">alarm_on
  </mat-icon>
</div>
```

in this way, the second `ngClass` is not working, it does if I remove the first one, but I'm not able to manage both at the same time.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by including a div:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
  <div [ngClass]="filter.class">
    <mat-icon 
        [ngClass]="{disabled: !filter.active}">alarm_on
    </mat-icon>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write so:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
  <mat-icon [ngClass]="{disabled: !filter.active,filter.class }">alarm_on
  </mat-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesnt work, it creates an error in the html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use object array syntax and include all checks under the same ngclass attribute as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
  <mat-icon [ngClass]="{filter.class : true, 'disabled' : !filter.active }">alarm_on
  </mat-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, but this doesnt work, it creates an error in the html